# Is it OK to start bounty for already answered and kinda popular questions (I posted)?

Tags: discussion, bounties

<sub>I found some similar questions, but nothing answers my situation.</sub>

For example, I think about these questions, I posted some time ago:

- [Is it safe to parse a /proc/ file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713451/is-it-safe-to-parse-a-proc-file)
- [Defining a variable in the condition part of an if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655284/defining-a-variable-in-the-condition-part-of-an-if-statement)

So I was wondering if it's OK (will not be interpreted by the SO community as something bad) to start some bounty on my own questions, which are already answered, award the already accepted answers (as they are really good) **not immediately, BUT after 6 says**, for example (just before the expiration of the bounty).

This will put my questions in the featured section for 6 days and will give the opportunity to be seen by more SO users, which will be useful for some of them.

If it's OK, what type of bounty should I start?

Comment: I read all the rules it looks fine to me!

Comment: Just be a bit careful. Continuously adding new bounties to your most upvoted questions (with the intention of attracting even more upvotes) is not *that* appreciated.

Comment: @BoPersson - I'm gonna do this just once, but yes, that's what bothers me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, by all means go ahead. And if you want to reward an existing answer, choose the bounty type "Reward Existing Answer" which is explicitly meant for that. As the explanation for it says

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Comment: I thought about this, but as this will stay for, let's say, 6 days and will not be awarded immediately, made me think before actually doing it. So I decided to ask.

Comment: @KirilKirov You can award the bounty sooner than that if you wish (a day after you started it). But I wouldn't worry.